# Undefined index 0 php laravel (Might be duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

This might be a duplicate, but i couldn't found any solution to my problem. 
I am retrieving few records from database and trying to display them in view. But always getting **Undefined index: 0** Exception. 
Here's controller code:

```
public function gettopfirms(){
    $top = Top::all();
    foreach ($top as $tFirm) {
        $topFirms[] = Firm::whereId($tFirm['id'])->get()->toArray();
    }
    return view('top', compact('topFirms'));
}
```

And here's the view (top.blade.php) code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($topFirms as $firm) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($firm[0]); //or $firm[0]['name']
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

And here's the Error:

```
Undefined offset: 0 (View: xxxxx/resources/views/top.blade.php)
```

Here is when i simply print array in view

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7092
        [rank] => 147
        [name] => Grupo Grana y Montero (GyM),
     )

)
Array
(
 [0] => Array 
  (
     [id] => 2 //And So On
```

Don't know what's wrong am i doing, struggling and googling, didn't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you probably do not check if the array is set or not. So the solution should be like this i.e.:

```
<?php
    foreach ($topFirms as $firm) {
        if (!isset($firm[0])) {
            continue; 
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($firm[0]); //or $firm[0]['name']
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

You might also want to filter it out earlier so here:

```
public function gettopfirms(){
    $top = Top::all();
    foreach ($top as $tFirm) {
        $topFirms[] = Firm::whereId($tFirm['id'])->get()->toArray();
    }
    $topFirms = array_filter($topFirms);
    return view('top', compact('topFirms'));
}
```